# ICS ListView background disabled when set onclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, gridview, onclick, pressed

I'm working on an Android application with ListView/GridView.

Since I set an onClickListener on the convertView (The view I return in the getView() method of my Adapter), the cell's background doesn't shine anymore when pressed. 
I know I can set my own drawable (with a specific pressed state) in my xml layout file (with value 'background') but I'd like to keep the original one (like when no onClickListener is set).

Can somebody tell me how I can keep the original background (with pressed state, ...)?

Thank you

PS: Sorry for my poor English, I'm French

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an Adapter view, why don't you add OnItemClickListener ?.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using an onItemClickListener on the Listivew (instead of an onclickListener on the view returned on the getView() method) solves the problem.

Is this better to use an onItemClickListener or the other way is fine too? (except for the problem I had?)

Comment: Both the methods are fine.However, if you want your list items to be focusable, you should use onClickListener. OnItemClickListener won't work in that case.